# Wordpress username-based rating plugin

Tags: wordpress, rating

I'm trying to make a **Wordpress** website, and I need a **rating plugin** that allows every registered user vote only once. I've found some plugins that control the voting system by user IP or cookies, but this is not valid for me. Does anybody know if there is any plugin that allows me to do what I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to try Elementous Rating Manager (keep in mind that it's a premium plugin). You can set group of users that will be able to see rating form (guests / registered users / guests and registered users). Also you can choose logging strategy (cookie / IP / cookie and IP / by registered user id). I think it would fit your needs.